# Освещение почему-то без теней, DirectX9

Tags: c++, c, directx

Загрузил модель, пытаюсь осветить. Создаю источник света над моделью:

```
 // включаем свет в сцене
Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, true);

// создаём материал и устанавливаем материал
D3DMATERIAL9 materialAll;
materialAll.Ambient = D3DXCOLOR(255, 0, 0, 1);
materialAll.Diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(255, 0, 0, 1);
materialAll.Specular = D3DXCOLOR(255, 0, 0, 1);
materialAll.Emissive = D3DXCOLOR(0, 0, 0, 1);
materialAll.Power = 5.f;
Device->SetMaterial(&materialAll);

// создаем, помещаем в систему и включаем источник света
D3DLIGHT9 point;
ZeroMemory(&point, sizeof(point));
point.Type = D3DLIGHT_POINT;
point.Diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(255, 255, 255, 1);
point.Specular = D3DXCOLOR(255, 255, 255, 1) * 0.6f;
point.Ambient = D3DXCOLOR(255, 255, 255, 1) * 0.6f;
point.Position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.f, 30.f, 0.f);
point.Range = 1000.0f;
point.Attenuation0 = 1;
point.Attenuation1 = 0;
point.Attenuation2 = 0;

Device->SetLight(0, &point);
Device->LightEnable(0, true);

// устанавливаем режим автонормализации векторов и режим отображения бликов
Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, true);
Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, true);
```

Однако почему-то не производится затенение — вся модель равномерно насыщенная по всей площади.

*Попробовал заменить освещение на насыщенно-синее — модель стала чёрной, то есть источник света применяется.*

Comment: @Arhad источник света имеет белый свет ведь. Или я что-то не так понял?
D3DXCOLOR(255, 255, 255, 1);

Comment: Ошибка вышла. Но всё равно, какой цвет вы ожидаете в результате? Ведь освещение в Direct3D — это всего лишь покомпонентное умножение. То есть *(255, 255, 255) \* (255, 0, 0) ⇒ (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) \* (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) ⇒ (255, 0, 0)*.

Comment: @Arhad тогда я ничего не понимаю. Пример из книги, немного скорректированный(красный материал + белый свет) выводит все так, как нужно. А здесь вот такие проблемы..

Comment: @Arhad дада, затенение неосвещённых участков. Понял цвет на синий, модель почернела. Соответественно та строка не помогла. Но, я включаю источник света после его создания.  Device->SetLight(0, &point);
    Device->LightEnable(0, true);

Comment: Возможно, у вас проблемы с моделью освещения. Попробуйте добавить `Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SHADEMODE, D3DSHADE_GOURAUD);`. Просто есть подозрение, что по умолчанию у `D3DRS_SHADEMODE` задано нулевое значение, которое ничего не обозначает.

Comment: @Arhad увы, и снова мимо, изменений не зафиксировано.

Comment: 1) Что с нормалями? Задаются ли они, и если да, то как? 2) Если нормали заданы, можете ещё попробовать подвигать источник света в разные стороны. Если общая освещённость модели при этом будет меняться — значит затенение есть, но по какой-то причине все нормали смотрят в одну сторону (значение по умолчанию?).

Comment: @Arhad нормали присутствуют, и они правильные вроде(два случая, рассчитывал в ручную и выгружал из файла). Подвигал источник, общая освещённость не изменяется в обеих версиях нормалей.

Comment: @Arhad сама модель - 3D модель(wireframe object(*obj))